# How to create a Sandbox Environment in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-lambda

I am trying to create a Sandbox playground in AWS for Users to practice some resources for 30min, after that, all resources should be deleted and account temporary account should also be deleted.

I got some information like Cloud Formation, Lambda and IAM combined can be used, Or AWS Control Tower also but I have no idea where to begin with.

Temporary account creation automation I understood, for deletion also I want to automate, Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: Do you want to give every user their own AWS account, which you will delete, or are you talking about IAM accounts? 30 minutes is a short time to play with AWS. I have a few ideas but I need your question clarified before I suggest them.

Comment: I will give them temporary account generated using AWS Organization and Lambda then same account i want to delete after 30 min, I can increase this time to 45min if that is not sufficient

Comment: That could end up with your console showing a HUGE number of removed accounts. Have you considered giving them a VPC and IAM user, then removing those? That gives you sufficient isolation. What do you expect people to be able to do that's useful in 30 minutes?

Comment: Using resoucess like Database services, EC2, S3

Comment: An RDS database might take 15 minutes to spin up, including the time in the console. Suggest you rethink what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it

Comment: In the meantime, AWS has set up some useful Best Practices documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/best-practices-creating-managing-sandbox-accounts-aws/